# Entity Framework table valued Functions - default entity mappings

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying out the `table-valued-function` support in Entity Framework 5, and I would like to map the result of a `TVF` to an entity. However, the `TVF` does not return all of the columns of the entity, and so EF is giving errors that

> entity column * is not mapped by the result of the TVF.

I can't remove those fields from the entity that aren't in the `TVF` result, because they're required fields.

Is it possible to adjust the function result mapping in the EDMX such that the missing entity fields get some default value when returned from the result of a TVF?

I'm not going to be using the results to write back to the service, so I'm not concerned with consistency issues that might result if I did.

Comment: No. You need another data type or modify TVF to return all columns for the entity.

Comment: Add this as an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another data type or modify TVF to return all columns for the entity.